# Find the limit of $\frac{\sin(n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

lim$\frac{\sin(n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}$ = lim $\sin(n)^2$ lim $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. We know that lim $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$. We have the property that if lim $s_n$ = $s$ and lim $t_n$ = $t$, then lim $s_nt_n = st$. However, the limit of $\sin(n)^2$ does not exist, so we may not use this property. The range of $sin(n)^2$ is, however, bounded. How can I complete this proof?

Comment: Im not sure what I am missing but is it not obvious it goes to zero, and I don't think this is real analysis

Answer (score 7):

Since $0 < \sin^2(n) \le 1$, $0 < \frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. So since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, the squeeze theorem gives $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin^2(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $(u_n)$ is bounded and $(v_n)$ tends to $0$, then $(u_nv_n)$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$$
is to say that for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ there is some number $k$ such that for all $n$ greater than $k$, $\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - 0\right| = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right| < \epsilon$. We also know that $0 \leq sin(n)^2 \leq 1$ for all $n$, so
$$\left|\frac{sin(n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}\right| = \left|\frac{sin(n)^2}{\sqrt{n}} - 0\right| < \epsilon$$
for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ where $n > k$, the very same $n$ and $k$ we used in determining that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$$
Thus it must also be the case that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{sin(n)^2}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$$